# AWS Network Printing

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

I am trying to build a module where I am able to send a print command (Json Request) from my mobile to a lambda function. The lambda function should execute a print command which should be send to print on a network printer. I have been trying to search online and in documentation but unable to find how I can execute print command in AWS.

The mobile device should ideally be from internet able to hit the API Gateway which will internally route to lambda function which will generate generate the necessary document for printing on a network printer. The client executing the print command will specify the printer name. I have searched and found that websockets are required to be used but I am not sure whether I need to register network printers to execute print command on the desired printer over web socket. I am struggling to find how I can register network printer. Not sure whether this is the correct approach?

Any help would be great

Comment: Where would you be printing? How would that place be connected to AWS or accessible from the Internet? What do you mean by "execute a print command", given that this normally involves an application and an operating system? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: What do you mean by "network printer"? Is there some standard for printers that are on the Internet and can be reached from anywhere? Printers normally reside on a private network and are not reachable from the Internet. Or do you have a network connection between an Amazon VPC and a corporate network, and the printers are on the corporate network?

Comment: Hi, is this done? how you achieved it ?. I too have a use case to execute print job from my lambda function, I can able to telnet my printer ip from my lambda ,but not sure on how to do the printing